# java, MySQL and Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, save, transient

I have 2 classes: A and B such that B extends A.
Using hibernate, A is a normal concrete Entity, with an associated table, and everything there is fine.

B is defined so that it extends A, and A and B are Serializable, and has 2 extra members for which I have the @Transient annotation. I do not want these to be saved in DB, and for all I care, to me all rows in that table are just instances of A, persisted. 
Target is to occasionally save B instances in the session.
However at some point I need to save a B object in DB (as if it were an A). I do not have or need a DiscriminatorColumn or anything like that.

I have tried things like:

```
session.saveOrUpdate((A) b);
```

... with b an instance of B. This failed.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess that you've added `@Entity` to your class `B`. This creates an *entity class hierarchy* - with the need to distinguish the different entity classes. If you remove the annotation, the column is not needed anymore.